# 'this' undefined in npm package

Tags: node.js, meteor, google-api, npm, google-authentication

I am trying to authenticate with Google through OAuth2, and I am using the googleapis NPM package. To do this, I am creating a small local package to use in my project:

Package.js

```
Npm.depends({
  "googleapis": "2.0.1"
});

Package.describe({
  name: 'google-tokens',
  summary: 'Library for requesting Google API tokens',
  version: '0.0.1'
});

Package.onUse(function (api) {
  api.use(['underscore', 'http', 'service-configuration', 'oauth', 'accounts-oauth'], ['client', 'server']);

  api.addFiles('lib/tokens_client.js', 'client');
  api.addFiles('lib/tokens_server.js', 'server');

  api.export(['Tokens']);
});
```

tokens_server.js (package)

```
Tokens = (function() {
  Google       = Npm.require('googleapis');
  OAuth2Client = Google.auth.OAuth2;
  var my       = {};

  my.fetchTokens = function(code) {
    var clientId     = Meteor.settings.google.CLIENT_ID;
    var clientSecret = Meteor.settings.google.CLIENT_SECRET;
    var redirect     = Meteor.settings.google.REDIRECT_URL;

    oauth2Client = OAuth2Client(clientId, clientSecret, redirect);

    var response = Async.runSync(function(done) {
      oauth2Client.getToken(code, function(error, tokens) {
        done(error, tokens);
      });
    });

    console.log(response);
    return response;
  };

  ....
```

However, the above code returns

```
Exception while invoking method 'addChannel' TypeError: Cannot set property 'transporter' of undefined
I20150316-23:33:03.520(1)?     at AuthClient (/Users/madsh/Programming/Projects/youtubr/packages/google-tokens/.npm/package/node_modules/googleapis/node_modules/google-auth-library/lib/auth/authclient.js:25:20)
I20150316-23:33:03.520(1)?     at OAuth2Client (/Users/madsh/Programming/Projects/youtubr/packages/google-tokens/.npm/package/node_modules/googleapis/node_modules/google-auth-library/lib/auth/oauth2client.js:38:23)
I20150316-23:33:03.520(1)?     at Object.my.fetchTokens (packages/google-tokens/lib/tokens_server.js:11:1)
```

Which referes to this part inside the node_modules folder in the .npm/package/node_modules/googleapis folder, which contains the following

```
'use strict';

var DefaultTransporter = require('../transporters.js');

/**
 * Base class for authentication clients.
 */
function AuthClient() {
  this.transporter = new DefaultTransporter(); <---------- Failing line
}
/**
 * Export AuthClient.
 */
module.exports = AuthClient;
```

I have no idea why this is happening, any advice?

Comment: Should that be `new OAuth2Client(clientId, clientSecret, redirect);`? Key being the missing `new`.

Comment: Any reason you’re using this instead of the official accounts google package?

Comment: Yeah because I want to store several access tokens per user account, and these should not be used for logging in. This is not possible with the accounts packages afaik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create the auth client as an instance, i.e.

```
var client = new Oauth2Client(...
```